# d3 rect not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to display the legend (caption?) of some data.
For each part of the legend, I append a rect and a p to a parent division.
The problem is that rect are not showing up.

Here is my code:

```
var groups = {{ groups|safe }};
groups.forEach(function(group, i) {
    var div = d3.select("#collapse-legend");
    div.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 17)
        .attr("height", 17)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return c(i); });
    div.append("p").text(group)
});
```

Now, when I check the content of my web page, I get both rect and p, but rect:

1. is not showing up
2. seems to have a width of 0 (showing its area with firefox)

Is there some mistake in my code? Are there better ways to achieve this? I am very new to javascript and d3.js so please be indulgent ^^

## Update

So this is what I ended with.
HTML:

```
<div ...>
    <svg id="legend-svg"></svg>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// set height of svg
d3.select("#legend-svg").attr("height", 18*(groups.length+1));

// for each group, append rect then text
groups.forEach(function(group, i) {
    d3.select("#legend-svg").append("rect")
        .attr("y", i*20)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .style("fill", function (d) { return c(i); });
    d3.select("#legend-svg").append("text")
        .attr("x", 25)
        .attr("y", i*20+15)
        .text(group);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `x` and `y` attributes of the `rect`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, nothing changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG elements like `<rect>` cannot be direct children of html `<div>` elements. You must put them inside an `<svg>` container element.

Comment: this is why ^^^ it's confused the hell out of me before but yeah youll have to alter your HTML and append <rect> to <svg>

Comment: Alright, I am now able to display ONE rect. I guess I still have to translate the rest of them and tweak a bit to get them at the front of each legend, but yeah, this is the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SET X + Y values for rect :

```
.attr("x", 50)
.attr("y", 50)
```

Comment: I didn't know JSFiddle, just let me some time and I will try to set one :)

Comment: sweet, shouldn't be too difficult to fix once that's set up

Comment: Okay so I tried to set a light version of my code, I hope this does not change anything to the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/tj50gz3L/2/